# Cannot run tablet emulator in android studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, tablet, android-studio-2.0

i have upgraded my android studio from 1.0.0 to 2.1 preview 4. The problem is that my tablet emulator is not running now. Actually emulator starts but APK file does not launch in the emulator

[This is my sdk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhplE.png)

[and this is my tablet specifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvjcD.png)

kindly help me

Comment: Was it running in previous version ?

Comment: ya it was running fine on previous version

Comment: Have you installed intel haxm ? [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/14/troubleshooting-intel-haxm) may help you.

Comment: @Shree i have tried this also but cannnot install haxm because my system is not supported for VT-x